# Automation Account rubook query

Tags: azure-automation

[Check Image For Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Obd.png)Once we go to automation account, click any Runbook and go to edit PowerShell runbook we can see check-in option before test pane and in my account check-in options is degraded so please help to enable that option.

We are trying to commit with source control for that check-in option should be enabled.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots may clarify what you are asking, since the issue is with a gui element that seems disabled?

Comment: Please click https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Obd.png

Answer (score 0):

To enable the checkin option and use it, please follow the instructions provided from below Microsoft documentation links which ever may help you. Note that i am providing multiple documentation links just to help you understand the process in a better way. Ideally the latest document out of them should be good enough. :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/source-control-integration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-source-control-integration-legacy

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-automation-source-control-13/

Regards,

Krishna

Comment: We followed the same link but still checkin option is not working